# Terraform EKS manage node groups : get the ec2 instance details

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

We are provisioning the node groups as [EKS managed node groups](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eks_node_group.html).

Once the node group is up we need to set some proxy on each of the node group instances, but the problem is that the outputs of the EKS managed group doesn't give any details about the instance details.

Once we get the EC2 instance id we can use data source and can use `remote_exec` to update the proxy.

Comment: @shellakkshelli Did you find a way to get AMI ID from EKS nodegroups somehow? I tried though I didn't find a solution where I can get AMI ID for EKS nodes. (We deployed using EKS Managed Nodes as well)

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't really help you because you'd need Terraform to run every single time the managed node group increases in size or replaces an unhealthy instance.

The normal thing with instances in autoscaling groups is to either bake things directly into the AMI and/or use user data to configure the instance with anything extra that isn't baked into the AMI. Unfortunately managed node groups don't allow either the AMI to be changed or custom user data to be passed in.

The [AWS containers roadmap on Github](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/) is tracking a [feature request for adding custom user data](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/596) but until then your only reliable option here is to forgo managed node groups and use normal autoscaling groups with your own AMI or user data to provide the configuration you need.

Comment: Understood but for us, it's not reliable to replace this, that's why we are looking for a workaround

Comment: Unless you have Terraform running in a loop on some CI/CD system every minute or so you then if you want Terraform to make these changes you are going to have instances being replaced and not changed how you want them to be. This is not a good fit for Terraform and you'd either want to look at reworking things in a way you can do (don't use managed node groups), push your technical account manager to see if custom user data can be prioritised and then wait months for it to happen, or rig together something using Lambda functions to react to the node pool instances changing and configure there.

Comment: I am curious why you think you need different configuration but absolutely cannot consider not using managed node groups over ASG backed worker nodes though.

Comment: the reason is simple we can't do a large change at this moment due.to business criticality. am just a developer:)